# Email messages not fully downloading : JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to write a program that retrieves email messages from my email provider's server and store them in my local database.

```
Message[] messages = folder.getMessages(); // get all messages
```

Due to unstable connections, some of the messages in `Message[] messages` miss some items, like:

```
Object content = message.getContent();
if (content instanceof String) {
    System.out.println((String) content);
    // Sometimes prints null because there was an internet
    // connection break during Message[] messages = folder.getMessages()
}
```

How can I tell that a particular message was not fully downloaded and redownload it again, and guarantee that what I have locally is an exact copy of what exists in my email server?

Comment: If the connection fails you should be getting a MessagingException or an IOException.  What does the [JavaMail debug output show](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) when the connection fails?